# Force jersey to put header and body of PUT request into single TCP segement

Tags: jersey

Is it possible to force Jersey to put both header and body into single TCP segment and basically to avoid the IP fragmentation?

According to my investigation, the jersey write the header and body in two separated steps (the method com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(ClientRequest):

```
<skipped>
writeOutBoundHeaders(ro.getHeaders(), uc);
<skipped>
writeRequestEntity(ro, new RequestEntityWriterListener() ...
```

Could anybody suggest an approah to avoid IP fragmentation, or maybe suggest an other library where I could control IP fragmentation when sending JSON requests?

[Two TCP segments, the second one is that with "09"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aazlk.png)